# How do I get data from multiple tables if the agency_code doesn't match

Tags: oracle, query, plsql

I have a table with these fields

```
Employment_Form (table name)
employee_number
full_name
agency_code
```

The second table is

```
HumanResources(table name)
employee_number
full_name
agency_code
```

The assignment is to find the records that have a typo for agency_code on the Employment_Form table.
The data in the HumanResources table is said to be 100% correct.

I am not sure how to best approach this. I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Just select rows where employee_number matches and agency_code doesn't. Do you have any sample code that you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using this select:

```
select ef.employee_number,ef.full_name,ef.agency_code
from Employment_Form  ef, HumanResources hr
where ef.employee_number = hr.employee_number
and ef.agency_code <> hr.agency_code;
```

Here you select all the columns of the `Employment_Form` table, fetching only those rows with matching `employee_number` and wrong `agency_code`.

If that `full_name` is the same on both tables, you can either use it, instead of `employee_number` , like this

```
select ef.employee_number,ef.full_name,ef.agency_code
from Employment_Form  ef, HumanResources hr
where ef.full_name = hr.full_name
and ef.agency_code <> hr.agency_code;
```

The output would be the same.

Hope this helps.